# how to catch @id from a cell address knowing its value - Webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can I get the element @id knowing its name displayed on the page? 
His address on the site is:

```
//tr[@id='jqg223']/td[5]
```

code site:

```
td aria-describedby="blablabla" style="text-align: left;" role="gridcell" title="">G02</td>
```

his name/value is e.g. `G02`.
He will need to extract the number (223) from jqg to the variable which will be incremented by 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the element, then call **getAttribute** method to retrieve id.

Eg:
if you want `td` element id:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'G02')]")).getAttribute("id");
```

if you want `tr` element id:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'G02')]/..")).getAttribute("id");
```

With `G02` as variable:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), '" + variableName + "')]")).getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks Naveen for you answer.

Comment: Added answer with variable, it is basically concatenation. You can also try String.format method.